# Filter http://magento.stackexchange.com questions

Tags: discussion, magento2

Is it possible to filter http://magento.stackexchange.com questions, so I won't see any Magento2, for instance, questions / answers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you can go to https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/preferences/ and at the bottom of the page you will see `Ignored Tags`. Fill in `magento2` in there and  you should not see those questions anymore.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

A shortcut to this user preference is in the sidebar for all Stack Exchange communities, though it's not labeled terribly well. Select the "edit" link next to "Favorite Tags".

[image]

Once you click "edit", you'll see an area to select Favorite Tags as well as Ignored Tags:

[image]